# "Unprocessed input" error using `cdo` in loop with variable

Tags: shell, cdo-climate

I am trying to embed a `cdo` line in a shell script with variables. As a command line it works, but not in a script.  This is the `cdo` line:

```
cdo -expr,'T_mask=((T > 200 ))' file_in.nc file_out.nc
```

In the shell script I want to run it for three different temperature thresholds, *e.g.* 200, 250, 300.

This is the code:

```
T_string='T_mask=((T > '
fileA='file_in.nc'
fileB='file_out.nc'
for T_var in 200 250 300; do
    cdo_string="'$T_string$T_var))'"
    cdo  -expr,$cdo_string  $fileA $fileB
done
```

I get the following error:

```
cdo (Abort): Unprocessed Input, could not process all Operators/Files
```

What did I miss?
Are the hyphens set right?

Comment: Re *"The `echo` gives..."*: there's no `echo` in the code.

Comment: True..had forgot to include it...

Comment: Please revise the question and either: 1) remove the reference to `echo` if it's not relevant, or 2) if it is relevant include `echo` in the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$T_string` variable seems needless.  When using similarly named shell variables, always use curly braces.

Try this:

```
fileA='file_in.nc'
fileB='file_out.nc'
for T_var in 200 250 300; do
    cdo  -expr,'T_mask=((T > '"${T_var}"'))'  "${fileA}" "${fileB}"
done
```

Comment: Great! It works now with the curly braces. Thanks a lot :D